# Adding a custom file type in Vim

Tags: vim, file-type

I want to create a custom `ft` which incorporates the `c` syntax highlighting and a highlighting depending on the characters at the start of the line .

Suppose if I call the new extension `.mib` . I can add:

```
syntax on
filetype on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.mib set filetype=c*
```

to display `c` syntax highlighting for the `.mib` files.

If in the same source file there co-exists another set of codes in some other language which are pre-pended by a `@@`.

How to distinguish [maybe in a different color other than that used for `c` highlights] these lines keeping the `c` code highlights for the rest of the code, if the prepended lines are a part of an undefined `ft`?

How to include the dual syntax highlights, if the `@@` prepended lines are a part of an already defined `ft`?

I am also aware of

```
:setfiletype html.c
```

for dual highlighting but I am particularly interested in highlighting the prepended lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your own autocmd is working well for you, you could just use another one to define a new syntax match for your new extension:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.mib syn match Error "@@.*"
```

This will highlight from each occurrence of `@@` until the end of that line, using the `Error` highlighting defined in the c.vim syntax file.

You can use any existing highlighting group you want, or define your own:

```
au ColorScheme * hi mibHighlight guibg=red gui=italic 
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.mib hi syn match mibHighlight "@@.*"
```